# Will we be able to have kids if we follow brahmacharya for 12 years?

Tags: sex, brahmacharya

I read that following brahmacharya for 12years activates a special nadi in our bodies and our energies start flowing upwards, so when I get married, will i be able to have kids?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If one becomes father at say when he is 28 years old, then he can complete the vrata when he is 40 years old. So impossible is nothing --- as Adidas claims :D